# How to preselect option in select box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, selection

I have one select box with various options.

When a page loads then one option with a value, for example 10, should be preselected with jQuery.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When the page loads run this (you can put it in `<body onload="//put code here">`):

```
$("option[value='10']").attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: You'll need to remove the descendant operator (space) from the selector for it to work. :o)

Comment: +1 I prefer this approach more so than using `val()` to set these. I'm not even sure how `val()` is supposed to work if you are presenting a multiple-select listbox...

Comment: @Funka - If it is a multiple select, it will accept an array of values to set. *example* http://jsfiddle.net/VArCZ/2/

Comment: @Adam, how to select it based on the select id?

Comment: Just use `$("#myId")`

Answer (score 24):

**Test the example:** http://jsfiddle.net/VArCZ/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mySelectBox').val('10');

});
```

Although, jQuery wouldn't be required for this if the intial value will be static:

```
<select id='mySelectBox'>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='10' selected='selected'>10</option>
    <option value='15'>15</option>
</select>​
```

Comment: +1 Correct of course! I might add that with `.val()` you supply the value between the `<option></option>` tags, not the `value=` attribute. So in the case of `<option value="10">Ten</option>` you would use `$("#mySelectBox").val('Ten')`

Comment: @Doug - Actually, if there is a value attribute present, it matches against that first. If no value attribute, then it tries to match against the text content. But thanks for the +1. :o) *updated example:* http://jsfiddle.net/VArCZ/1/

Comment: Dude.. seriously? I always thought that method was #fail... I need to read the source more. Thanks!

Comment: @Doug - Full disclosure: I had to do a quick scramble to make sure I had it right. Happens more often than I care to admit. :o)

Answer (score 1):

In the latest jQuery version this works for me:

```
$("option[value='10']").prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Above code is working you can use following code:

```
$("option[value='10']").attr('selected','selected');
```